# How to auto categorise items in Sheet2 from Sheet1 - find string

Tags: string, vba, excel

In Sheet1, column A contains the items and column B the category. So one item is associated to one category (but one category can have more then one item).

Sheet1:

```
Cat         Animal
Movie       Media
Music       Media
Gasoline    Car
Water       Food
Fotball     Sport
Dog         Animal
```

Sheet2 contains the items that are going to be categorised. I want column B in Sheet2 to be autofiled with help from Sheet1 (as much as possible).

Sheet2:

```
Lion
BMW
Computer
Dog
Hamburger
Water
```

The correct autofil would be:

```
Lion
BMW
Computer
Dog         Animal
Hamburger
Water       Food
```

Comment: Why not use `VLOOKUP`?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something from the above, the following formula in Sheet2 B1 will suffice:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

... copied down.

Set-up:

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

If you don't want the `N/A` error to appear in case the item has no matching category, use the following variation:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

**Result:**

[image]

Simple application and description of the formula can be found [here](http://howtovlookupinexcel.com/).

Hope this helps.